# Interact with locator that has dynamic value in playwright

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, playwright

I want to interact with the following locator

```
<select name="ship[0][596211][address]" id="ship_0_596211_address" class="" title=""></select>
```

using this line of code:

```
await page.locator('#ship_0_596211_address').selectOption('24553');
```

My problem is that `596211` is a dynamic value that for every flow will be different so my line of code with hardcoded value will never work. How do I interact with this specific locator with a dynamic value?

What line of code do I need, also considering that there are other similar locators on the page like:

```
<select name="ship[1][596211][address]" id="ship_1_596211_address" class="" title=""></select>
```

Comment: Yes, name is present in all select elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `name` attribute is present in all `select` elements, you can use [wildcard selectors in css](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcard-selectors-and-in-css-for-classes/) to match the dynamic value. Something like:

```js
await page.locator('select[name^="ship[0]["][name$="[address]"]').selectOption('24553');
```

**What it means?**

1. `select[name^="ship[0]["][name$="[address]"]` - targets all `select` element whose `name` attribute starts with `ship[0]` and ends with `[address]`.

Below I've created a small sample in `html` and `css` which depicts that it targets the expected `select` and applies styling to it. In playwright, you can use it to locate your element.

```css
select[name^="ship[0]["][name$="[address]"] {
  /*Try changing above to select[name^="ship[1]["][name$="[address]"]. 
for applying style to second select. */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

select:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #007bff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<select name="ship[0][596211][address]" id="ship_0_596211_address" class="" title="">
  <option value="24551">Address 1</option>
  <option value="24552">Address 2</option>
  <option value="24553">Address 3</option>
</select>

<select name="ship[1][596211][address]" id="ship_1_596211_address" class="" title="">
  <option value="24551">Address 5</option>
  <option value="24552">Address 6</option>
  <option value="24553">Address 7</option>
</select>
```